# Testing two resolved promises with Angular/Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I have a service called `myHttp` that returns a promise, and a controller that calls `myHttp` twice with different parameters.

To test the controller, I'm attempting to mock `myHttp` with Jasmine spyOn like so:

```
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$q_, myHttp) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $q = _$q_;
    deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred2 = $q.defer();
    spyOn(myHttp, 'call').and.callFake(fake(1)).and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    spyOn(myHttp, 'call').and.callFake(fake(2)).and.returnValue(deferred2.promise);
```

where `fake` is a function that retrieves the parameters to be used in `myHttp` call.

Problem is that I cannot declare twice the same mocked function. I get the following error from Jasmine:

> Error: call has already been spied upon

How can this test be fixed? this is the [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/BL0EAYHWrzrBDkkWs9xt?p=preview)

Javascript:

```
angular.module("mymodule", [])

.service('myHttp', function($http,$q){
    this.call = function(obj) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({url:obj.url, data:obj.data})
              .then(function (response) {
                  defer.resolve(response);
              });
        return defer.promise;
    };
})

.controller('ctl', function($scope,myHttp) {
      $scope.read = function (id){
          var data = {};
          data.id = id;
          myHttp.call({url:'/getStudent', data:data})
              .then(function(response) {
                  $scope.id = response.id;
                  $scope.name = response.nm;
                  $scope.classId = response.clsid; 

                  var data2 = {};
                  data2.id = $scope.classId;
                  myHttp.call({url:'/getClass', data:data2})
                      .then(function(response) {
                          $scope.className = response.nm;
                  });
              });
     };
});



describe('Testing a Controller that uses a Promise', function () {
  var $scope;
  var $q;
  var deferred;
  var $timeout;

  beforeEach(module('mymodule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$q_, myHttp) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $q = _$q_;
    deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred2 = $q.defer();
    spyOn(myHttp, 'call').and.callFake(fake(1)).and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    spyOn(myHttp, 'call').and.callFake(fake(2)).and.returnValue(deferred2.promise);

    $controller('ctl', { 
      $scope: $scope, 
      myHttp: myHttp
    });

    $scope.read(1)

  }));

  function fake (option) {
    if (option==1)
       return {url:'/getStudent', data: {id: 1}};
    else
       return {url:'/getClass', data: {id: 10}};
  }

  it('should resolve two promises', function () {

    var student = {
      id: 1,
      nm: "John",
      clsid: 10
    };

    var clazz = {
      id: 10,
      nm: "Math"
    };

    deferred.resolve(student);
    $scope.$apply();

    deferred2.resolve(clazz);
    $scope.$apply();

    expect($scope.id).toBe(student.id);
    expect($scope.name).toBe(student.nm);
    expect($scope.classId).toBe(student.clsid);
    expect($scope.className).toBe(clazz.nm);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spy on `myHttp.call` once and change your fake function call to take in the request parameters and return an object based on the request.

```
var student = {
  id: 1,
  nm: "John",
  clsid: 10
};

var clazz = {
  id: 10,
  nm: "Math"
};

spyOn(myHttp, 'call').and.callFake(function(obj) {
  if (obj.url == '/getStudent') {
    return $q.when(student);
  } else if (obj.url = '/getClass') {
    return $q.when(clazz);
  }
  return $q.reject('Mock not supported');
});
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n3ceflqwvJVK4ZtW2Xbv?p=preview) for full working example.

And as a side, your http call be reduced to just

```
.service('myHttp', function($http,$q){
    this.call = function(obj) {
        return $http({url:obj.url, data:obj.data});
    };
})
```

because `$http` already returns a promise.

Also, you can also use the angular [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) to mock your http calls instead of using the jasmine spyon. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rA5St6OVvnzZ7UlM2VjI?p=preview) which uses `$httpBackend` with a slight change to `myHttp.call`.

Answer (score 0):

The very general answer is that you don't have to create your spy at a top-level beforeEach. You can use a beforeEach that's closer to the individual spec or even create the spy in the it statement. You could also check something in your fake to see which promise you want to return based on the parameter the fake is being called with.

However, what condition are you actually wanting to check for? Usually there's something that should happen after the promise is resolved, and you actually want to look at that. It's easier to give you specific feedback if you say what it is you're aiming for in the end rather than saying what you think is the right solution and asking us how to get to that.

Please see also [$q.defer: You're doing it wrong](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/)